# AppVeyor not producing artifacts

Tags: appveyor, approval-tests

Trying to get insight into why our tests are failing in AppVeyor, by looking at some of the [Approval](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net) files it produces.

We tried configuring AppVeyor to collect the `.received` files, like this:

```
artifacts:
- path: '**\*.received.*'
```

We also tried collecting everything, like this:

```
artifacts:
- path: '*'
```

but no artifacts were collected.

Answer (score 1):

AppVeyor only publishes artifacts on *_success_*.

See also:

- https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/1649-how-to-keep-a-build-artifact-when-tests-fail
- https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/#pushing-artifacts-from-scripts